# How to stack multiple fa icons with custom positions and size

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am currently using the font awesome library and one of the icon which i need needs the upgraded version of it. But i am not allowed to upgrade the version in my project as of now. So, what i am looking for is to include the two icons in a single one. I need the fa-user-plus icon and this icon can be made by combining  fa-user and fa-plus icon. But, I am facing difficulties in placing it in exact position. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning for `fa-plus` and smaller font size to position it where it must be

```
.fa-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

.fa-user {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.fa-plus {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
}

<div class="fa-wrapper">
    <span class="fa-user"></span>
    <span class="fa-plus"></span>
</div>
```